# Cannot build on launchpad

Tags: apt, ppa, packaging, launchpad

I have succesfully uploaded my app to launchpad:However it fails to build on both i386 and amd64.
Here is the link:
https://launchpad.net/~mkamenjak/+archive/ubuntu/bugappppa/+packages

Here is the build log from launchpad:
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/190190054/buildlog_ubuntu-utopic-amd64.bugapp_1-2ubuntu2_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Here are the contents of my debian/control file:

```
    Source: bugapp
    Section: web
    Priority: optional
    Maintainer: Mario Kamenjak <mkamenjak77@gmail.com>
    Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
    Standards-Version: 3.9.5
    Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>

    Package: bugapp
    Architecture: any
    Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
    Description: A webapp for bug.hr
     <insert long description, indented with spaces>
```

Here are the contents of my debian/rules file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/make -f
    %:
        dh $@
```

Why does it not build and how exactly do I fix this?

**Note:** I never packaged anything before.No experience in either .deb or .rpm packaging whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Dobey's answer, it is more easy/quick to track dependencies using `pbuild` or `sbuild`. Check [SimpleBuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SimpleSbuild).

However if you have small tool to package with low bandwidth connect, myself prefer building on launchpad directly as I don't have a ready setup of `chroot` environment, sometimes working on low resource machine.

From the buildlog:

```
   dh_auto_test -a
make[1]: Entering directory '/build/buildd/bugapp-1'
qmltestrunner -input tests/unit
make[1]: qmltestrunner: Command not found
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'check' failed
make[1]: *** [check] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/buildd/bugapp-1'
dh_auto_test: make -j1 check returned exit code 2
```

It clear that you need the `qmltestrunner` tool for build, check it's package:

```
$ dpkg -S qmltestrunner
qtdeclarative5-dev-tools: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner
qtchooser: /usr/bin/qmltestrunner
```

1. So add them to build dependencies.

   ```
    Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), qtdeclarative5-dev-tools, qtchooser
   ```
2. Then upload it again.

**Update:**

I have used `pbuild` long time ago and I looked again for new things. I think [`cowbuilder` <sup>①</sup>](https://wiki.debian.org/cowbuilder)
is the simplest available tool.

1. Install it.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install cowbuilder
   ```
2. Edit the `pbuildrc` config

   ```
    # this is your configuration file for pbuilder.
    # the file in /usr/share/pbuilder/pbuilderrc is the default template.
    # /etc/pbuilderrc is the one meant for overwriting defaults in
    # the default template
    #
    # read pbuilderrc.5 document for notes on specific options.
    MIRRORSITE=archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

    COMPONENTS="main universe"
   ```

   Two known problems:

   - The `MIRRORSITE=archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` will not work. (seen in trusty, no such problem in wily)
   - `COMPONENTS="main universe"`, default is `main` only, `universe` is needed for [`cowdancer`<sup>②</sup>](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cowdancer/+bug/747053).
3. Create the cow image

   ```
    sudo cowbuilder --create
   ```
4. Build your debian source pacakge

   ```
    sudo cowbuilder --build yourpackage.dsc
   ```
5. Find the built packages in:

   ```
    /var/cache/pbuilder/result/
   ```

**Reference:**

① [Debian Wiki: `cowbuilder`](https://wiki.debian.org/cowbuilder) (`pbuilder` wrapper)
② [LP Bug#747053: cowbuilder requires universe to be enabled in pbuilderrc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cowdancer/+bug/747053)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the dependencies required to build your app, in the *Build-Depends* section of the *debian/control* file.

Also, you should use *sbuild* or *pbuilder* to test local builds of your package, before uploading to a PPA on Launchpad, to ensure the package will build.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a list of dependencies automatically?

Comment: My app is quite simple,just a qml app that loads a webpage with forward,backward and refresh buttons.(I used the deprecated webkit webview element).

Comment: Also how do I use sbuild or pbuilder?