# What to use for building ubuntu/debian packages?

Tags: packaging, pbuilder, debuild, workflow, sbuild

I've been inspecting different howto's and guides on how to build packages lately. And there seems to be a [lot](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) of [ways](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingFormalBackports) one could [go](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) [about](https://wiki.debian.org/AutomateBackports) [it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto). So I'm a bit confused about what exactly to use. That is I'm trying to see the whole picture. What tools exist? What are the relationships between them? Which are wrappers for which? Which are better suited for what? Like, `apt-get source` is [probably](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53014/why-use-sbuild-over-pbuilder#comment274726_199184) mainly targeting users, not developers. [Better alternative](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto#Downloading_Source_Packages_Using_dget) must be `dget`. Which are the alternatives for which? To name a few there are `pbuilder`, `pdebuild`, `pbuilder-dist`, `cowbuilder`, `sbuild`, `debuild`, `dpkg-buildpackage`, `fakeroot`. And there must be a lot more I don't even know about. What are the most common workflows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I managed to find out. First, there is [this brief description](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html#hierarchy) which is what I mostly ask here.

At the core of the build system lies `dpkg-buildpackages`, which uses `fakeroot`, which in its turn runs `debian/rules` (which is a makefile) to bulid a package. And that might be enough if you're going to build a package for internal use for the release you're running it in.

If on the other hand you're aiming at contibuting to `debian`/`ubuntu`, you're going to use at least `debuild`, which runs `lintian` and signs the files.

If you want to target different `debian`/`ubuntu` releases, you're going to use `pbuilder`, which among other things builds packages in a clean environment not clobbered with your already installed packages to see the actual dependencies. One might consider using `pbuilder-dist` to simplify matters even more.

There's `pdebuild` which is said to be "pbuilder way of doing debuild". I don't see it running `lintian`, but that might be not in line with `pbuilder` way.

Then there's also `cowbuilder`, if you want to speed up building packages (wrapper around `pbuilder`?). There are also tools for building from `git` repositories, I haven't dug into.

**UPD** I'm told on `#debian-mentors` that "`sbuild` behaves the same as the `buildd`, less surprises", that "`pbuilder`'s support for experimental is just wrong", that "OTOH `sbuild` still misses something to take away network from the build process", and that `pbuilder` is not maintained. Taking away network is needed since building packages should not rely on it being present, they shouldn't download anything.

[`schroot` from experimental](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=schroot.conf&manpath=Debian+experimental) is supposedly able to isolate (unshare) network.

Comment: +1 for that link to packaging tools hierarchy, I just got some interest for this topic for few days. `cowbuilder` seems the easiest tool (compared to what I saw with `pbuilder`). I have resumed steps in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/548815/cannot-build-on-launchpad/716481#716481 . BTW, you don't have to deal with any `chroot` tool directly. sbuild / pbuilder take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say much about your source environment.

If it is open source and just one project (one control file under the `debian/` directory) then https://launchpad.net is a really good solution. More or less, you have to get the files right and they take care of the rest.

Getting the files right is a little bit of magic for me, even now, but there is a plethora of documentation on how to create a package. You could start with a very simple example that works and then take the time to add other options/features as you move forward. That way you do not have to learn all the ins and outs all at once.